# Problem of working light bulb

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

1. The first light bulb works for '$a$' hours and does not work for '$b$' hours.
2. The second light bulb works for '$c$' hours and does not work for '$d$' hours.

This month there will be a situation when both light bulbs will light up at the same time.

How many hours after that will the moment come when both lights are off?

There are examples of data to check the solution:

1. $a=4; b=3; c=5; d=2;$ Answer is 5
2. $a=6; b=7; c=14; d=1;$ Answer is 59
3. $a=3; b=1; c=8; d=2;$ Answer is 19

How can this value be found?

(I realized that in some cases the answer is equal to the smallest common multiple of $(a+b)$ and $(c+d)$, but this is rather an estimate from above, since geometrically we find the moment when the segments completed one after the other end together.)

Comment: As a starting point to the analysis, the intervals when the first light is on are $~[~m(a+b) - b,m(a+b)~] ~: ~m \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ and the intervals when the second light is on are $~[~n(c+d) - d,n(c+d)~] ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.~$  So, you are looking for the smallest value $~T_0,~$ such that there exist $~m,n~$ with $$m(a+b) - b \leq T_0 \leq m(a+b), ~~\text{and} ~~n(c+d) - d \leq T_0 \leq n(c+d).$$  At this point, I personally am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: You could start by reducing $c$ and $d$ modulo $a+b$, and reducing $a$ and $b$ modulo $c+d$. Now repeat with the new numbers you get until it stabilizes. As with the usual Euclidean algorithm, you get coefficients along the way. Do you see how you can use them? Try some examples.